# Installing AjaxTerm with NginX using SSL

Tags: ajax, ssl, https, console, nginx

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and trying to install AjaxTerm using https. Any guide to use NginX to serve AjaxTerm using https protocal?

Also I would like to put AjaxTerm to be served under https://localhost/ajaxterm/ instead of the default http://localhost:8022.
How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: there should be a configure file for changing port no.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you would like to setup ajaxterm to a remote server & not really localhost.

Setting up at a url like /ajaxterm would be difficult, but you can easily set it up at a subdomain like ajaxterm.yourserver.com with following lines inside the http directive in nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ajaxterm.yourserver.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8022;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
}
```

This should get you http://ajaxterm.yourserver.com running for you. To get it running on https, you can tweak the instructions for apache [here](http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Ajaxterm)